# Why can't I get an $location from the $injector?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to use the `$location` service outside of the scope using `$injector`.

When I run the following code I keep getting an error

```
   angular.injector(['myApp']).get('$location');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the error in the question.

Comment: what does "use `$location` outside of the scope" mean?  what scope are you referring to?  the `$scope` service and the `$location` service don't have any dependency to each other, but generally `$scope` is what people are meaning when they say scope.  Without code or error messages, it's not obvious what you are trying to do, much less why you are having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The `$location` service is not part of the `myApp` module, it is part of the internal `ng` module.

To get the `$http` service, use:

```
var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get("$http");
```

The `$location` service depends on the `$rootElement` service which is created at bootstrap time. To get the `$location` service use:

```
var $rootElementModule = function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$rootElement', angular.element(document))
}

var $location = angular.injector(['ng',$rootElementModule]).get("$location");
```